# CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage failed for avcomposition

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, avfoundation, gpuimage

i'm trying to extend GPUImageMovie in GPUImage library to AVComposition, through using AVAssetReaderVideoCompositionOutput as the frames input.
but when reaching:

```
- (void)processMovieFrame:(CMSampleBufferRef)movieSampleBuffer {
..
CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,        
coreVideoTextureCache, movieFrame, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth,   
bufferHeight,    GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &texture);
...
```

i get:
Failed to create IOSurface image (texture)
Movie CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage failed (error: -6683)

which turn out to be:
kCVReturnPixelBufferNotOpenGLCompatible -6683

The pixel buffer is not compatible with OpenGL due to an unsupported buffer size, pixel format, or attribute.
Available in iOS 4.0 and later

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out?  I have the same problem

Comment: I don't think it will work on any Buffers that you manage memory for.  Every time I create one and let it allocate the memory it works, every time I allocate the memory it does not.